# How to get from SqLite DB many-to-many ralation with order

Tags: sql, sqlite

In my DB I have two "business" objects:

- City (id: int, name: varchar)
- Connection (id: int, other fields that are not needed here) - It describes the list of Cities that is on path (i.e. for bus that are going from city to city)

To join this tables I have one more table connection_city:

- id
- city_id - id of city
- connection_id - id of connection
- number - the number in connection path

The problem for my is how to get all connections with path from DB in the fastest way.

Now I'm quering for all connection_city that have `cc_id = from_id OR cc_id = to_id` and then I'm parsing it in my Java (Android) code.

Comment: There is no `cc_id` column. Show some example records and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a CTE might be helpful for code clarification.

```
With cteConnection as (select id, city_id, 
                       connection_id, number from connection_city);
SELECT *
FROM City c
INNER JOIN cteConnection cte 
        ON cte.city_id = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN connection ct 
        ON ct.ID = cte.connection_id
```

Comment: I don't quite understand it. What is this CTE?

Comment: This CTE is what's above the main SELECT statement : select * [...]. It's not required, but used to help make readable the query.

Comment: No Android has a recent enough SQLite version yet.

Comment: In which case, the left outer join should not infer the cte, rather have a join (select id, city_id, from connection_city) x on x.connection_id = ct.id or an outer apply with a where clause acting as the join.